# CloudFront: Internally redirect to specific file in S3 bucket file using RoutingRule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS CDK to set up a new private S3 static site bucket with a CloudFront configuration to serve it. The structure of the S3 bucket is as follows:

```
bucketname/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/
bucketname/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/index.html
bucketname/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/config
bucketname/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/config/config-dev.js
bucketname/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/config/config-tst.js
bucketname/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/config/config-acc.js
bucketname/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/config/config-prd.js
```

For example, when I deploy version 4.5.6-SNAPSHOT of a static site, a new folder 4.5.6-SNAPSHOT is created in the `bucketname` S3 bucket. At the moment, index.html consists of the following:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://dev.somesite.com/config/config-dev.js" />
  </head>
  <body>...</body>
</html>
```

I have managed to configure the cloudfront configuration to map https://dev.somesite.com/some-path to `bucketname/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/some-path` using an S3 `destinationPrefix`. When I navigate to `https://dev.somesite.com/` the index.html is served and the config js is loaded. So far so good.

However, as you can see in the HTML, the reference to `config-dev.js` is still hardcoded. I would like the CloudFront configuration to internally (not 30x) redirect the call `https://dev.somesite.com/config/config.js` to `bucketname/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/config/config-dev.js` instead. I have tried setting up a `RoutingRule` using a diversity of `KeyPrefixEquals` and `ReplaceKeyWith` values, to no avail. I am trying to set up a configuration similar to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html#redirect-rule-examples) one (example 2).

My CDK script results in the following routing rule:

```html
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/config</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>1.2.13-SNAPSHOT/config/config-dev.js</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

However, a call to `https://dev.somesite.com/config/anything` is not being redirected to the required config-dev.js file. Would anyone know the best approach for this matter? Is setting up a RoutingRule the right approach at all?

**[edit]**

I use an S3 `destinationPrefix=1.2.3-SN` setting to ensure that the new folder is uploaded in bucket `bucketName` in a new destination(Prefix)Folder '1.2.3-SN'. Simultaneously I have configured CloudFront's `originPath` to `/1.2.3-SN` to ensure the folder is set as "root" folder. This works as expected; navigating to https://dev.somesite.com/ results in `bucketname/1.2.3-SN/index.html` being served.

What I'd like to accomplish is having the ability of "rerouting" any call to https://dev.somesite.com/config/**.js to a single configuration file located in `bucketname/1.2.3-SN/config`. The reason why I'd like to do this is to ensure that the script reference in index.html does not need to change per environment, while at the same time shielding off other config files not needed in the current environment.

Comment: What's the Origin Path set to on the bucket origin in your CloudFront distribution?  Setting it to `/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT` (leading but not trailing slash) seems like what you are looking for -- not routing rules.  I have no idea what a `destinationPrefix` is but it sounds like it's fixing the problem from the wrong direction.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My AWS configuration makes use of an originPath as you mentionded. I have updated my original post to indicate my intent.

Comment: Okay, yes, now I see what you're doing.  There's only one way to do it and that is with a Lambda@Edge Origin Request trigger that rewrites the path before sending the request to the origin server... but now I'm uneasy offering that suggestion because I don't understand where the `-dev` in `config-dev.js` comes from.  Naming the same file different things in different environments seems like an antipattern that should be fixed on the front rather than in the back.

Comment: When the static site is build (and before it is uploaded to the S3 bucket), several configuration files are added to the output build folder (config-dev.js, config-tst.js, etc). Do you suggest using a different approach? For instance using a folder architecture like config-dev/config.js, config-tst/config.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run Lambda functions at the CloudFront edges. It's called [lambda@edge](https://aws.amazon.com/tr/lambda/edge/)
When the CDN gets a request(*Viewer request*), you can set up many things such as:

- Forward to a specific bucket
- Set up response headers
- ...

I believe this is what you need.